# Segmentation Fault before even starting execution

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I wrote this code yesterday, during a live contest on codeforces, and it produces segmentation fault before even executing the first line in main().
The program didn't even print "test"

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "test";
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n, s, k, ans = 0;
        cin >> n >> s >> k;
        int arr[n+1];
        memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            cin >> t;
            arr[t] = 1;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {//cout<<"test";
            if (s+i <= n && arr[s+i] == 0) break;
            if (s-i > 0 && arr[s-i] == 0) break;
            if (s-i <= 0 && s+i > n) break;
            i++;
        }
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A lot of non-standard code here. `int arr[n+1];` can blow up horrible ways. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` can blow up horrible ways. `using namespace std;` is standard and legal, but can still blow up horrible ways. But... If you don't flush the output after `cout << "test";`, a whole lot of stuff can happen before you see it printed. If it ever gets printed. Try `cerr << "test";` or `cout << "test" << endl;` and see what happens

Comment: Poked at it a bit, but cannot reproduce. What are you using for program input? Could you add the input to the question?

Comment: error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant - Which compiler you are using?

Comment: If it is a contest then you might be expected to gracefully handle syntax-breaking input. Then trusting that `cin >> t;` succeeds would be the error to fix.

Comment: There isn't any input, the program stops execution before taking the input.....cout << "test" << endl; will probably work

Answer (score 3):

Your program does not print `"test"` because you need to **flush stdout**. If you do not flush it, SO will keep that text in a buffer and might wait for an appropriate moment to output it. Instead, force SO to print it using:

```
cout << "test" << std::endl;
```

Or

```
flush(stdout);
```

Comment: A note on why flushing is not guaranteed by default: Flushing can be expensive and slow. The typical use case is to only flush when you have to  because the buffer is full, the data must be sent immediately, or the user needs to see something before continuing.